# To find a column name in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have to find the column name which has a particular value. For example : I have to find all the column names which has a value 'Availability' stored in that particular column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find column name that contain `availabvility` you could use [`INFOMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx):

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%Availability%';
```

or [`sys.columns`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx)

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.columns
WHERE Name LIKE '%Availability%';
```

**EDIT:**

To find specific value in all tables you could use [`ApexSQL Search`](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx) Plugin

> Text search
>
> **Search for text, numbers, dates and unique identifiers in your tables
>   and views**

[image]

<sup>Image from: http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx</sup>

Comment: Actually my column_name is not Availability.The value stored in that column is 'Availability'. for eg : Like we store 102 in field Student Id.

Comment: This answer will not meet my requirement actually

Comment: That looks good..but i don't have this tool..not able to download also

Comment: is there any method by writing script ?

Comment: Yes, listing all user tables/columns from metadata tables with datatype `char/varchar` and then using execute dynamic-sql.

Comment: Thanks @las2025 i installed ApexSqlSearch..Solved my issue..Thanks for your kind help and information

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, you have any shortcut to find the value level check. You may need go and check the respective tables and use pattern matching(i.e. like '%availability%') to find the value.

My shortcut would be: You should have general idea about you possible column names which can contain the expected availability value. Then use lad2025 data dictionary queries to find the relevant tables and the column names. Then you can go ahead and run a separate select query on each table/ column.